# Can black holes slow down a planets time to months whilst millions of year pass elsewhere?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, time-dilation, space

Writing some sci-fi and want to see how accurate I can get this. Let's say there's a planet (call it A) next to a black hole and then Earth somewhere far away.

Is it in any way possible for the time dilation caused by the black hole to make mere months pass on A whilst have the entire formation of our solar system, Earth, evolution, human society occur?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how many months, and how many millions of years, specifically.

A similar scenario was in the sci-fi film, Interstellar. The calculations for that time dilation effect can be found here: https://relativitydigest.com/2014/11/07/on-the-science-of-interstellar/

For Schwarzschild (a non-rotating) black hole, the time dilation equation goes something like:

$t_0 = t_f \left[1 - \frac{r_s}{r}\right]^{1/2}$,

where $r_s$ is the Schwarzschild radius.